# What signal is sent during a windows reboot after an automatic update

Tags: python, windows, signals

I have python script that runs on a windows machine and when the machine receives updates and shuts down for a reboot I would like to listen for that signal and gracefully handle cleanup in my script.

When a process is killed via normal means my understanding is that the process is sent the `SIGTERM`signal.  This signal can be caught and processed.

However it seems that when the system performs an automatic reboot due to windows updates there may not be a `SIGTERM` signal sent?  Is `SIGKILL` sent instead?  I understand that `SIGKILL` cannot be caught and the process is pretty much dead, this I can live with - it just changes my strategy on how I will recover.

I understand the process by which I can listen for signals in Python, **what I am specifically asking for is clarification on what signal is sent to a process when windows automatically reboots after a windows update**

Comment: Just to make sure you understand: Windows is not actually sending these signals, Python (and/or the C runtime library used by Python) is emulating them.

Comment: @HarryJohnston What are the signals sent that C is able to interpret and then pass along to Python? Most importantly, what messages are sent processes when during an automatic reboot.  I believe windows only includes `SIGILL` and `SIGTERM` for compatibility reasons.

Comment: Windows itself does not have the concept of signals.  The method used depends on whether it's a console application, a GUI application, or a service; search MSDN for `SetConsoleCtrlHandler`, `WM_QUERYENDSESSION`, or `SERVICE_CONTROL_SHUTDOWN` respectively.  I'm not familiar with all of the details.  I can confirm that the C runtime library doesn't emulate `SIGTERM` and doesn't even define `SIGKILL` (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdkz3x12.aspx) so if you're seeing `SIGTERM` in your Python code, it's the Python interpreter that's generating it.

Comment: @HarryJohnston, MSVC `SIGABRT` and `SIGTERM` can only be used with `raise`. `SIGINT` and `SIGBREAK` are raised from the console's `CTRL_C_EVENT` and `CTRL_BREAK_EVENT`. `SIGFPE`, `SIGILL`, and `SIGSEGV` are raised for certain Windows exceptions.

Comment: CPython's `signal` module is built on the CRT's signal handling. It installs a `SIGINT` handler, and it has a `kill(pid, signal)` function that calls `GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent` when the signal is `CTRL_C_EVENT` and `CTRL_BREAK_EVENT`, and otherwise tries to kill the target via `TerminateProcess`. For setting custom console, GUI, or service handlers, you'll need either ctypes or PyWin32.

Comment: @eryksun: the CRT documentation says "`SIGINT` is not supported for any Win32 application" but it isn't clear to me what exactly this is supposed to mean.  Looking at the CRT source, it looks as if `SIGINT` is in fact implemented exactly as one might expect (by installing a console control handler) so probably the only issue is that the `SIGINT` handler runs in a separate thread, contrary to the C standard.  (Presumably CPython's signal module does whatever is necessary to maintain thread safety.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston, CPython's global interpreter lock (GIL) only allows one thread at a time to execute bytecode in the VM, and signal handlers are only executed by the main thread. CPython's [`signal_handler`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ab2c023a9432/Modules/signalmodule.c#l208) trips the signal to add a pending call for the main thread. For `SIGINT`, there's also an `Event` on Windows that allows Ctrl+C to break out of `time.sleep(seconds)` in the main thread, which is implemented via `WaitForSingleObjectEx` on the event.